# Some kind of grammar parsing but without brute force

Tags: algorithm, parsing

I have a list of "transformations"/"grammar" whatever you can call it of the form:

L -> L|LL|N

this means that L(letter) can be transformed in either 1 letter or 2 letterS or in one N(number)

I'm given a list of transformations and a sequence of numbers and an INITIAL move performed and I have to generate the minimum list of moves that generate the sequence of numbers given.

```
For example:

I have the transformations
A->BC
B->D
B->ED
C->F
C->FB
D->2
D->3
E->0
E->1
F->4

The sequence: 2 4 0 3
The initial move performed: A

So the minimum list would be:

1.(A, BC) [BC](initial move)
2.(B, D) [DC]
3.(D, 2) [2C]
4.(C, FB) [2FB]
5.(F, 4) [24B]
6.(B, ED) [24ED]
7.(E, 0) [240D]
8.(D, 3) [2403]
```

There are no loops for example A->AB or A->B , B->A etc
Brute force is not an option since the input of transformation is big ~1000 and the sequence to generate is ~30.

After an extensive search on the internet I found the CYK algorithm but after aplying it on my example it results that the sequence 2403 is not in the grammar(which is wrong).

I really don't see how should I proceed I am trying for days to solve this. Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't really seem like parsing. It's more like generating a sequence from a starting position.

Comment: Why isn't this parsing?  It seems he has a grammar and wants to expand grammar rules(he seems to be calling these "moves") to match a sequence.

Comment: @oren: Just saying "it doesn't work" isn't helpful to us and therefore not to you. So convince us you implemented CYK on this grammar correctly.  Otherwise you likely just have a bug.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Parsing involves using a formal grammar as a recognizer. That is, to derive meaning from a string written using the grammar. What the OP is asking for is a generator: to to produce a specific output by applying the grammar's production rules to a known starting state. Although both use formal grammars, they are fundamentally different operations.

Comment: @JimMischel: Point taken.  OP did pose the problem as "the sequence 2403 is not in the grammar" which is easily checked by attempting to parse that string with the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can apply [CYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm), the grammar must be in [Chomsky normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form), which means that you need to [eliminate the unit rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#UNIT:_Eliminate_unit_rules).

In other words, the rule `B->D` must be converted to two rules: `B->2` and `B->3`. Likewise, the rule `C->F` must be converted to `C->4`.

Once you've made those adjustments to the grammar, it will be in Chomsky normal form, so CYK will work. Of course, when displaying the parser results, any time you invoke one of the converted rules, you'll need to generate two lines of output. For example, the invocation of `B->2` should be displayed as `B->D` followed by `D->2`.

Comment: thanks for help now I understand why it didn t work. so there is no other algorithm instead of cyk that i can use?

Comment: @orenrevenge As with everything in software, there are many ways to solve the problem. That said, this particular problem seems especially well suited to CYK.

Comment: what is the general algorithm to eliminate unit rules ? this problem is too hard for a "introduction to programming" course...

Comment: @orenrevenge Eliminating unit rules means that if `A->B` and `B->3`, then the rule `A->B` is replaced with `A->3`. Keep in mind that if there are multiple values associated with `B`, then all of those values apply to `A`. Also, note that there could be a chain of rules, like `C->A`, `A->B`, and `B->3`. So after replacing the rules for `A`, the code needs to replace the rules for `C`.

Comment: @orenrevenge: This is for an "introduction to programming" course? You're right: it's not appropriate there. This is a fairly advanced topic.